Postgres 9.5 with Postgis 2.2
I'm in need to install a brand new Postgres installation using older versions. I'm in need since i want to upgrade to the latest version, and for compatibility issue i'm working on a dump of my main database.
When i try to find the correct Postgres version i'm unable to find a working repo where obtain Postgres 9.5.x and postgis 2.2 (2.5 is fine too). Does someone have a reliable repository  where i can get those packages?

don't. use a source install (ie tar,gz) and install all versions you need in something like /opt/, It used to be normal to do /opt/{softwarene}{version}/  to install multiple versions and use a bin in /opt/{software}/ to symlink to one of those versions to activate it. Installs like that are always possiible and do not depend on apt or a ppa that might conflict with the base system.

you can find all versions here https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/ and postgis is here https://postgis.net/stuff/

Thank for the reply. Those are the source, i need to recompile them right?

The tarballs should be pre-compiled: untar in /opt/{software}{version}/ (probably is the default) and there will be a readme on how to proceed (often you need to copy a bin to PATH if you use one version; if multiple versions are needed use /opt/{software}/ and add that one to PATH)
